# Check if date expires in less than 20day in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table shift and it has a field `expiry_date`.

I have a requirement to get a list of all shifts with an **expiry date in less than 20 days**. How can I achieve this in rails?

I tried something like this but it is returning me all Shifts that have **expiry_date 20 days ago** but I need which will expire in less than 20 days.

```
scope :20_days_to_expire, -> {  where('expiry_date < ?', 20.days.ago) }
```

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter between today and 20 days later:

```
scope :20_days_to_expire, -> {  where(expiry_date: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day + 20.days)) }
```

Comment: will this include if the expiry_date is exactly on the 20th day?

Comment: Maybe you need to add end_of_day in the second time https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/end_of_day